# commenting with login w/twitter or facebook connect

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter, facebook

Im building my blog in rails and I want to enable comments

I would like to have something posterous-like with a "facebook connect" and "login with twitter" option. The user can login with one of them and then post. No anonymous posts.

I dont want to add more login-services, just stay simple (i.e. no disqus)

How can I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would suggest [authlogic](http://github.com/binarylogic/authlogic), like Devenv said. The tutorial on [Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/160-authlogic) is very helpful. Also the author of authlogic himself created an [example application](http://github.com/binarylogic/authlogic_example) as a tutorial

Authlogic can be extended to work with facebook and twitter with authlogic plugins:

1. Facebook with [authlogic_facebook_connect](http://github.com/kalasjocke/authlogic_facebook_connect):

   ```
   $ sudo gem install facebooker
   $ script/plugin install git://github.com/kalasjocke/authlogic_facebook_connect.git
   ```

   then you can follow the Readme of [authlogic_facebook_connect](http://github.com/kalasjocke/authlogic_facebook_connect) on github
2. Twitter with [authlogic_oauth](http://github.com/jrallison/authlogic_oauth):

   ```
   $ sudo gem install oauth
   $ sudo gem install authlogic-oauth
   ```

   then you can follow the Readme of [authlogic_oauth](http://github.com/jrallison/authlogic_oauth) on github again

Now you can enable login via facebook or twitter. Authlogic can do a lot more than that. If you want to, you can enable your railsapp to use openid [authlogic_openid](http://github.com/binarylogic/authlogic_openid), too.

Answer (score 0):

There are plugins that help with these, though the only example of both I have seen is this one (which I have not used):

http://tardate.blogspot.com/2010/01/released-authlogicrpx-111-gem-now-with.html

Probably worth looking at the code even if you don't use this plugin.

Answer (score 0):

What I use is [authlogic](http://github.com/binarylogic/authlogic) with [authlogic_facebook_connect](http://github.com/kalasjocke/authlogic_facebook_connect)
and of course you'll need [facebooker](http://github.com/mmangino/facebooker) and set up a facebook app etc...
authlogic takes some time to setup so - [podcast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/160-authlogic)